# Laravel 8 Gate base on Levels in Database Artisan Migration error

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I'm new to Laravel 8 and I'm implementing Gates base on user levels in my database.
Very similar to roles.

My table levels look like this
id, name, gate, timestamp

Here is my code in /app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider

```
...
...
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        
        /*
         * Gate base on Level in the Database
         */
        $levels = Level::all();
        foreach ($levels as $level) {
            $gate = $level->gate;
            $gateid = $level->id;
            Gate::define($gate, function (User $user) use ($gateid) {
                return $user->checkLevel($gateid);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

If I leave the code like this when I run the first migration 'php artisan migrate' I get this error:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravelportail.levels' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `levels`)

If I comment my code inside the boot the migration work.
After that I can seed the database
Then uncomment my code in the boot.

Any idea how I can do this without this migration error and commenting and uncommenting my code.

Comment: For know I fix my issue with Schema and a If statement.  if(Schema::hasTable('levels')){ ...

Answer (score 0):

You could define a single Gate in a manner that defers model queries until it is migrated.

```
       $this->registerPolices();

        Gate::define('level', function (User $user, $gate) {
            $level = Level::where('gate', $gate)->firstOrFail();
            return $user->checkLevel($level->id);
        });
```

Usage of the gate would be different. For example in your routes:

```
if( Gate::allows('level', 'example-level') ){
    echo 'You are in this level';
} else {
    echo 'You are not in this level';
}
```